# Can't get error from returned object- ng-file-upload- Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-file-upload, ng-img-crop

I'm using ng-file-upload with ngImgCropExtended.

All works great, the only issue I have is that when validation fails it fails silently, with no notification to the user.

I added  ngf-validate-fn="validate($file)" to my upload button, and can see the error, but cannot access or check for the error.

My html:

```
 <button 
         id ="bannerUpload" 
          ngf-validate-fn="validate($file)" 
          ngf-accept="'image/*'" 
          ngf-min-width = "1600" 
          ngf-max-size = "1.3MB" 
          ngf-pattern="'.png, .jpg, .JPEG, .jpeg'" 
          ngf-select="handleFileSelect($file)" 
          ngf-drop = "handleFileSelect($file)" 
          ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*"></button>
```

controller:

```
.controller('galleryController', ['$scope', '$attrs', '$http', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, $attrs, $http, Upload, $timeout) {     

    $scope.validate = function($file ){
          console.log($file);
          console.log( $file.constructor );
    }
```

File is logged with an $error object, but I can't seem to access it.  I can access other properties of the file oject, such as name.

If I log the constructor function, it gives me

```
function File() { [native code] }
```

If I log the File object it gives me ( for example )

```
File{}
   $error: "minWidth"
   $errorMessages: Object
   $errorParam: 1600
   $ngfBlobUrl:  'theUrlOfTheImage'
   $ngfHeight: 274
   $ngfWidth: 316
   lastModified: 145437567099
   name: nameOfMyImage.jpg
```

I can access normal properties like name with $file.name. $file.$error returns undefined.  $file.$error() returns nothing, no error no log.  Also tried $file.validate.$error as the doc says

ngf-validate-fn="validate($file)" // custom validation function, return boolean or string containing the error.
                  // validate error name: validateFn

Finally tried JSON.stringify( $file ) but this returns an empty object {}

Comment: `ngf-validate-fn` is for when you want to add custom validation and the validation error should be returned by that function.

Comment: To access the validation errors with ngf-* validation directives use form element access like the first jsfiddle sample in the docs or use ngf-model-invalid="invalidFiles" and access the $error property of each invalidFiles.